# clojure regex to match words and everything inbetween

Tags: regex, clojure

This is more of a regex question than Clojure, but I am testing it in Clojure.

```
(re-seq #"\w+" "This is a test. Only a test!")
```

produces:

```
("This" "is" "a" "test" "Only" "a" "test")
```

I want to have this:

```
("This" " " "is" " " "a" "test" ". " "Only" " " "a" " " "test" "!")
```

Where I get all the words, but everything else between the words is included too.
  I don't care for the period and space if they are seperate `"." " "` or together ". "

Is this simple to do with a regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following regex:

```
\w+|\W+
```

---

```
> (re-seq #"\w+|\W+" "This is a test. Only a test!")
("This" " " "is" " " "a" " " "test" ". " "Only" " " "a" " " "test" "!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably could use `\b` which matches word boundaries and use `string/split`. The only problem is that it will match the beginning of the string too:

```
(rest (clojure.string/split "This is a test. Only a test!" #"\b"))
```

This won't be lazy either.